# 2d list to 3d list in python

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have two lists given by,

```
list1 = [[2,3,1,3],[2,4,6,2]]

list2 = [[1,2,3,4],[4,3,2,1]]
```

How would one convert to a 3d list?

So that to access list1, one would:

```
list3[0] = list1

list3[1] = list2
```

where print list3 would provide:

```
[[[2,3,1,3],[2,4,6,2]],[[1,2,3,4],[4,3,2,1]]]
```

I have tried adding, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: clarify your question as lists and tuples of lists are not the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) the tuples/lists to avoid creating references:

```
list1 = [2,3,1,3],[2,4,6,2]

list2 = [1,2,3,4],[4,3,2,1]

from copy import deepcopy

l3 = list(map(list, map(deepcopy,(list1, list2))))


print(l3[0])
print(l3[1])
[[2, 3, 1, 3], [2, 4, 6, 2]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 3, 2, 1]]
```

If you have lists not actually tuples you can remove the outer map:

```
l3 = list(map(deepcopy,(list1, list2)))
```

Comment: The `zip` calls aren't needed.

Answer (score 4):

```
list1 = [[2,3,1,3],[2,4,6,2]]
list2 = [[1,2,3,4],[4,3,2,1]]
list3 = [list1, list2]
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer is contentious, but it produces the desired data structure in the simplest possible way.